# How can I run atomic read/write operations or transactions in Azure CosmosDB with MongoDB API

Tags: azure, transactions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to execute 2 reads and 1 write in a collection atomically, making sure that there are no writes between the reads and the write.

I tried following several docs and tutorials but every one of them uses batches and containers instead of mongoDB collections.

I also tried to use transactions in mongoDB client sessions but the transactions are still not atomic.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(System.getenv("mongodb")));

    ClientSession clientSession = mongoClient.startSession();
    clientSession.startTransaction();
    try{
        if (!auctionRepository.checkAuctionStatusAtomic(auctionID, mongoClient)){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).entity("Auction is not open").build();
        }
        if(!auctionRepository.checkAuctionPriceAtomic(auctionID, bid.value, mongoClient)){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).entity("Bid value is too low").build();
        }
        auctionRepository.updateCurrentPriceAtomic(auctionID, bid.value, mongoClient);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        clientSession.abortTransaction();
    }
    clientSession.commitTransaction();
```

Is there any way of executing these operations atomically?

In a transaction or batch for example.

Comment: Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/use-multi-document-transactions#requirements), multi-doc transactions only work in unsharded collections. Is your collection sharded or unsharded?

Comment: Due to some restraints it had to be sharded, however, in this specific situation there was a possible solution using an unique index.